# Finding the hypotenuse of a right triangle given the area

Tags: geometry

So, I have to solve this problem:

> The area of a right triangle is 4, let the hypotenuse be $a$:
>
> And there are 4 options to choose from:
>
> A) $a>1.3$ B) $a<1.3$ C) $a=1.3$ D) None of those

So, my reasoning is:

Let △ be a right triangle, with the right angle at C.

Then we know:

$a^2+b^2 = c^2$,

Area is $\displaystyle\frac{ab}{2}$

Since we have two equations with 3 variables there is an infinite number of solutions.

But we know that the product of the legs must be equal to 8. Let the legs have the same length so they are √8. Using pythagoras theorem, we know $(√8)^2 + (√8)^2 = 4 $.

If one leg is bigger than the other, then the hypothenuse must be greater than 4.

So my answer would be $a≥4$.

Is this reasoning correct? Is there a particular reason why my homework is using the length 1.3 at the answers?

Comment: @Raffaele Why is that? If a right triangle has two legs $b=4$ & $c=2$ it would have an area of 4 and a hypotenuse $a$ of 2√5, for which $a≥4$

Comment: $a^2=b^2+c^2=(b-c)^2+2 b c \geq  16$ therefore $a \geq 4$

Comment: But why complicate it so much? If you drop a perp from opposite vertex to the hypotenuse $a$ with length $h$, then $a \times h = 8$. $h$ has to be less than $a$ so $a \gt 1.3$ is the option you choose.

Comment: But don't know why _none of these_. Between the first $3$ options in the question, all possibilities are already covered.

Comment: @MathLover So, the reason why $h>a$ is because, &a>h& would imply that the triangle has no right angle, right?

But where does the value $a >1.3$ came from?

Comment: @MauricioVega If $ah = 8$ and $a > h$ then $a > \sqrt{8} > 1.3$.
Also note that $a > b > h$.

Comment: @Saeed Thank you so much

Comment: @MauricioVega You are very welcome